# Linq Count() on selected field

Tags: c#, linq

What would be the equivalent of SQL:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Count(PolicyNumber) ...
```

in Linq. I would like to do something like:

```
var distinctClients = clientPolicies
                .Select(i => new { i.ClientId, i.Name, i.PolicyNumber.Count() })
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList();
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Linq? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming PolicyNumber is a collection; I don't see why your code wouldn't work. Could you explain where you are having a problem?

Comment: Try to assign the result of `i.PolicyNumber.Count()` to a named property. Do you see a syntax error or an exception?

Comment: I get error: `Invalid anonymous type member declarator...` this in i.PolicyNumber.Count(). I guess I would need to do a group by of ClientId and Name. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var distinctClients = clientPolicies
            .GroupBy(i => new { i.ClientId, i.Name})
            .Select(g => new { ClientId= g.Key.ClientId, Name=g.Key.Name,Count=g.Count()})
            .OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList();
```

I didn't test that, but it should be close...

Comment: OP - This is the correct answer.  Note that in SQL you couldn't do the COUNT operation without a GROUP BY in your query.  Then note that this answer uses a LINQ GroupBy, taking the count from the resulting aggregate in the next step.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get error: Invalid anonymous type member declarator... at `g.Count()`. Any ideas?

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I was looking for @James Curran Thanks for your help friend